# Setting date from selectInputDate to object

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have a date controller which does various things. Once a calendar date is set, I want to pass the value from the date controller to another bean. The problem I have is that the `setPropertyActionListener` gets called before the user clicks on a date.

Is there a way to get the date from the `selectInputDate` *after* selection and pass to a bean?

This is what I tried:

```
<ice:selectInputDate popupDateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" renderAsPopup="true"  value="#{dateRangeDateContoller.end}" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{searchParameters.endDate}" value="#{dateRangeDateContoller.end}" />
</ice:selectInputDate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `partialSubmit="false"`.

Comment: does anyone know if that solved the problem? I'm facing the same problem but can't find an answer, sorry If I'm hijacking a thread but I didn't want to open a new one if this answers my question! thanks!

Comment: @BRabbit27 Did it solve your problem when you made the change? That should answer that question for you.